# Minecraft Forge: Item.Properties().tab() method cannot be resolved

Tags: minecraft-forge

Im Trying to add my item

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> TITANIUM = ITEMS.register("titanium",
            () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(CreativeModeTab.MISC)));
```

it says for .tab that "Cannot resolve method tab in properties" and it says for MISC that "Cannot resolve symbol"

Here is the entire code

```
import net.darkcrown.firstmod.FirstMod;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;

public class ModItems {
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS =
            DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, FirstMod.MOD_ID);

    public static final RegistryObject<Item> TITANIUM = ITEMS.register("titanium",
            () -> new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(CreativeModeTab.MISC)));

    public static void register(IEventBus eventBus) {
        ITEMS.register(eventBus);
    }
}
```

ive tried to see whether there is another method or maybe import issue but cant find anything can please help

Answer (score 1):

What version of forge/minecraft are you working on?

The Creative Inventory Tabs have been reworked for 1.19.3 (see [Minecraft Release Changelogs](https://feedback.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/11280166737293-Minecraft-Java-Edition-1-19-3)). Since then the `net.minecraft.world.item.Item.Properties.tab(CreativeModeTab)` method does not exist anymore.

The new way to add your items to creative mode tabs is described in the [forge documentation](https://docs.minecraftforge.net/en/latest/items/#creativemodetabevent):

```
// Registered on the MOD event bus
// Assume we have RegistryObject<Item> and RegistryObject<Block> called ITEM and BLOCK
@SubscribeEvent
public void buildContents(CreativeModeTabEvent.BuildContents event) {
  // Add to ingredients tab
  if (event.getTab() == CreativeModeTabs.INGREDIENTS) {
    event.accept(ITEM);
    event.accept(BLOCK); // Takes in an ItemLike, assumes block has registered item
  }
}
```

It works by subscribing to the CreativeModeTabEvent which is published whenever a creative mode tab is being built. You check whether the tab that is being created is the tab that you want to add your item to. If that is the case, you add your item to the tab using `event.accept(YOUR_ITEM)`